# is it possible to get info about which ip or computer, from git commit history or information

Tags: git, github

Just out of curiosity, is there a way to get which IP the commit came from, or what MAC address this commit is from?

For example, if I clone a repo from GitHub and I check the Git history to find out all information about this commit.

Comment: AFAIK `git show --quiet --format=raw HEAD` is pretty much all there is. i would not expect any machine information in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This information is typically collected on the server side, because it has a listener (ssh or https) which can put them in a log.
That is typically what does **[gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html)** (an [authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#access-control)) in [its log file](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#lff)

But one the client side, there is no listener, only a `git` command which will interpret the pack files it receives. It is only concerned with the repository data, not its origin.